# Object not copying. What can I do to copy them?

Tags: c++, oop, deep-copy

I am trying to write a soccer team register class (SocReg) in C++ which when the array of teams is full it will copy all the data in a new array with 10 more free spaces, destroy the existing one and then continue working.
However it seems those are not saved in the array, only the new ones get to be registered and the old ones are copied as "" nothing.

```
Team * tempTeams = new Team[theSize+10];
    for(int i = 0; i < theSize; i++){
        teams[i] = tempTeams[i];
    }
theSize += 10;
delete[] teams;
teams = tempTeams;
unused++;
teams[unused+1] = Team(teamName,color);
```

Here is my copy constructor in Team Class

```
Team::Team(Team& toCopy){
    tName = toCopy.tName;
    tCol = toCopy.tCol;
    unused = toCopy.unused;
    roster = new Player*[50];
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        roster[i] = toCopy.roster[i];
}
```

Have  done anything wrong here?

Comment: The canonical form of a copy constructor is `Team::Team(const Team& toCopy)`.

Comment: Thank you I forgot that too. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change

```
for(int i = 0; i < theSize; i++){
    teams[i] = tempTeams[i];
}
```

to

```
for(int i = 0; i < theSize; i++){
    tempTeams[i] = teams[i];
}
```

because at the moment you're copying data in the wrong direction, effectively storing empty strings.

Comment: OMG... I am really sorry for posting this stupid question. You are right. Coding for 4 straight hours in C++ sure is destroying. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're copying elements from `tempTeams` to `teams`; it should be the other way round.

`std::vector` would do all of this automatically for you.

Comment: Yea, you are right! I am so stupid! :/
I know but our instructor has forbitten the use of such datastructures